# Opposite to append - how to remove String using ToggleButton?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need your help.
I'm using ToggleButtons and when it's On it's adding value on a display.
My problem is to remove that value when it's Off.
Can you help me, please?

```
static boolean isempty=true;
public void changeButton(View sender) {
    ToggleButton btn = (ToggleButton) sender;

    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) sender).isChecked();

    if(on)
    {
        sender.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(59, 223, 59));
        if (isempty)
        {
            if (btn.getText().toString().equals("0")) return;
            display.setText(btn.getText());
            isempty = false;
    }
        else
        {
            display.append(btn.getText());
        }
        }
    else
    {
        if (btn.getText().toString().equals(btn.getText())) display.setText(""); // I tried but it removes all of String, I just want to remove one value...
        sender.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 100, 100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the original value somewhere in the view/activity when the button is toggled on and restore it when it is toggled off.

Comment: But how can I do it? I'm a total newbie.